# How do I know what version of Windows 7 I had before upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

A few weeks ago I've upgraded my Windows 7 to Windows 10.
Now, I need to know what version exactly I had back then in Windows 7 (Pro/Ultimate/Enterprise). How can I get this information from my currently installed Windows 10?

Comment: Do you have your windows 7 COA sticker with your license key on it? It should say the edition it was for

Comment: The Free W10 upgrade only allows same version upgrade so if W10 is Pro then W7 was Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do that.

1. You can open the Computer window by selecting "Computer" from the right side of the Windows Start Menu. The Computer window can also be displayed by clicking the "Computer" option in the left sidebar of any open window on the desktop. You can open the System control panel by first selecting "Control Panel" from the right side of the Windows Start Menu, then double-clicking the "System" option. You may also right-click the Computer icon if it is available on the desktop and select "Properties" from the pop-up menu to open the System properties window. Finally, if the Computer window is open, you can click on "System properties" near the top of the window to open the System control panel.
2. Download software names as "Produkey" from Nirsoft. It will give you OS name and version alongwith product key.

But in your case it depends on your windows.old folder. If you have not deleted windows.old then you can check "\Windows.old\system32\license.rtf" file in a text editor and look at the 2nd title row, it will tell you the exact Windows edition, as was initially installed.

Comment: As above or you can go Start Menu > Run > type winver > Press OK and get your About Windows pop up...

Comment: Glad to see you jumping in there to help answer questions. Only problem is, this doesn't answer the question "*How do I know what version of Windows 7 I had before upgrading to Windows 10*". You are only telling them how to find the current information.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Beginner Great effort of you in the first option described in your answer. Thumbs up for this... Actually, I took the second (and more convinient and faster) option and it worked just fine for what I needed. Thanks